# IllegalArgumentException not sure if I wrote the array right

Tags: java, arrays, exception, null, project

```
    gamePanel gp;
    Tile[] tile;


    public tileManager(gamePanel gp){
        this.gp = gp;
        tile = new Tile[10]; // this means we're going to create 10 types of tiles (water, grass, water, sand, etc...)
        getTileImage();
    }

    public void getTileImage(){

        try{
            tile[0] = new Tile();
            tile[0].image = ImageIO.read(requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/tiles/grass.png")));

            tile[1] = new Tile();
            tile[1].image = ImageIO.read(requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/wall.png")));

            tile[2] = new Tile();
            tile[2].image = ImageIO.read(requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/water.png")));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
        g2.drawImage(tile[0].image,0, 0, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
    }
}
```

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjeOb.png) [Second Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVdF0.png)

So I'm trying to add tiles inside my game but I don't get why is the error? I found this online so any suggestions how to fix that will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: You didn't get a "NullPointerExecution", you got an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: You are getting that error because the resource you are trying to obtain either doesn't exist in that path, resulting in returning `null` in a process that are marked as `requireNonNull`. In this case, either `grass.png` doesn't exist in that directory, or your path is incorrect. You can try a full path if the image exists, then refine so that you can use the correct relative path.

Comment: Because the field is marked as "requireNonNull", a value of `null` represents an illegal argument; thus the exception thrown. Without knowing your folder structure, the path is most likely the culprit.